# Is there a way to add a Sharepoint Survey App to a Sharepoint List (Possibly with a flow)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey, survey-list

I would like to be able to add a flow to a survey that would allow it go through and approval process and update a list within SharePoint. The only options that I'm finding for the Survey app now is to export to Excel.

Comment: Try going to Flow and adding a new Flow from scratch and connecting to the survey list.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike Mentioned, you can create a workflow with `Call Http Web Service` action to call SharePoint `rest api` for creating/updating new item in Survey list.

You can use sharepoint designer to add your workflow to your List. Detailed steps are [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/).

Here are the [references](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/09546d82-1ffc-4569-808c-1174c63474b4/how-to-add-new-sharepoint-online-survey-list-item-in-ms-flow?forum=sharepointdevelopment) for CRUD operation on List Item with Rest API.